# Endpoint for checking if user exists in system

Tags: email

I have question regarding users point of view of this endpoint

`/api/user` which requires POST data: `email=user@domain.com` and returns `{"user@domain.com": "exists"}`

I am concerned if users might think that service returns sensitive data. Service stores emails only for logging in purpose, and never shows to anybody, but I have an external app which might want to know if email in phone book is our user or not. Is there something what I might be worry about?

Comment: Considering the effort that spammers expend to gather valid e-mail addresses and verify that e-mail addresses are active (i.e., assigned and being used), the fact that somebody has used `user@domain.com` as a login ID could legitimately be considered sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes** - you should worry about this.

Email addresses are personal information; they are linked to an individual. As G-Man mentions, there is a spam risk in divulging what email addresses exist. But moreover, the fact that a particular person uses your site is private information, that you should not disclose publicly. All sorts of sites could potentially be embarrassing: porn is an obvious one, and a recruitment site could be too. You haven't told us what your site does; but even if it's something quite innocuous, the fact that a particular individual is a member is private information.